# ASP .NET MVC Application UML class diagram

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, uml, software-design

What is a correct way to draw a class diagram for an MVC web application?
For example, I have two Controllers (Controller1, Controller2), a Model (Model, which is a wrapper for some wcf service), and a View (Index.cshtml). Controller1 creates an instance of a Model and calls its methods. The View communicates with Controller1 and 2 using ajax. Controller2 sends an asynchronous messages to the View.

Comment: You are asking for behavior but a class diagram can not show that. So what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I was asked to supply a Class diagram. I've specified the communication methods (ajax/websockets) for dependency. If I use an ajax to call controller's action, I need to draw an arrow from the view to controller, don't I?

Answer (score 0):

As said, your class diagram can not express behavior. So basically it could look like this:

[image]

To picture the behavior you can use sequence diagram (but you did not ask for it).